# AVPlayer Synchronization using setRate:time:atHostTime:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

My goal: play MP3/AAC files from a web server (streamed, rather than downloaded in advance) in PERFECT sync between multiple iOS devices.

Two questions:

1 - Can AVPlayer stream existing MP3/AAC files, while continuing on to the next tracks in the background?  Meaning, assuming the phone is locked, or another app is in the foreground, if I am playing a list of multiple MP3/AAC files, and one finishes playback, will the next track begin playing seamlessly?

2 - Can the new `setRate:time:atHostTime:` method in iOS6 AVPlayer allow for synchronized playback between MULTIPLE iOS devices?  Meaning, I want to play audio in perfect sync between multiple iOS devices.  I read the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/setRate%3atime%3aatHostTime%3a), but it's a bit confusing and I can't find any sample code to see how it works:

Answer (score 0):

Matt's AudioStreamer is the best option for you , Avplayer and AVaudioplayer downloads the remote mp3 url synchronously before playing which takes time .

click [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html)

Comment: Ah, I know of Matt's Audiostreamer app, but I am more curious as to if there are any libraries built into AVPlayer/AVAudioPlayer or related libraries to help me synchronize audio playback across two or more iOS devices.  Make sense?

Comment: Airplay would be nice, but unfortunately you can not stream to MULTIPLE airplay devices from an iOS device as of now.  This can be done however using iTunes on OS X.